# How to implement one to many relation in mongoose with refs

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I have two schemas.
PostSchema:

```
export type PostDocument = Post & Document;

@Schema({ collection: 'posts' })
export class Post {
  @Prop()
  description: string;
  @Prop()
  title: string;
  // incorrect variant below
  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  })
  _id: ObjectId;
}
const PostSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Post);
export { PostSchema as PostSchema };
```

and UserSchema:

```
export type UserDocument = User & Document;

@Schema({
  collection: 'users',
})
export class User {
  @Prop()
  name: string;
  @Prop({
    type: [
      { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post', autopopulate: true },
    ],
  })
  posts: Post[];
}
const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
export { UserSchema as UserSchema };
```

But I still do not understand how to link the first table with the second.It was much easier to do everything in 1 table, but I'm interested in this approach with refs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should never name a Mongoose property `_id`. This is the fieldname internally used by mongoose to identify a single document. In you case I suggest to name it `userId` or `authorId` (assumed from the context of your code).

Nevertheless you basically have two options to define a one-to-many relationship in mongoose:

1. Define the ObjectId of a user in the Post schema.
2. Define an ObjectId array of Posts in the user schema.

Basically you have done both, which is possible, but not really the best approach. The problem here is that it is not easy to keep the two separate relations in sync with each other (remember: you are not working with a relational database and have to take care of removing references yourself).

**Suggested approach:**

In your case I suggest you to define only the ObjectId of a user in your Post schema (approach 1) and create a virtual property named "posts" in your user schema (like here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html#populate). This way it is easily possible to populate data from both directions and don't have to keep track of data synchronization, since the relation is only defined in post schema. The only issue you should tackle is to set this Post property to null if a user gets deleted. You should define a hook in this case.